# Como Deserealizo un array de objetos en ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

ya eh intentado de todo. Alquien que me pudiera ayudar

Asi es como mando mi objeto al controlador

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("editarTarjetaCapacitacion", 
        "TarjetaCapacitacion")",

        scriptCharset: "utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "appliction/json; charset=iso-8859-1",
        data: {
            InstructoresExternos: JSON.stringify(tarjetaCapacitacion.InstructoresExternos)
        },
        success: function (respuesta) {
            if (respuesta.errorCode != 200) {
                ErrorBottom(respuesta.mensajeError);
                return;
            }
            window.location.replace("http://" + window.location.host + "@Url.Action("Index", "TarjetaCapacitacion")");
        }
```

aqui es donde lo recibo

```
public JsonObject editarTarjetaCapacitacion(string[] InstructoresExternos)
   {}
```

lo que intento es obtener el arreglo y recorrerlo pero no puedo deserealizar el arreglo

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que hago es que en el `JSON.stringify` le mando directo el Array. Algo así

```
data: JSON.stringify{parametro: NombreDelArray}
```

Para cuando recibo el Array en el Server lo que hago es que tengo una clase que contiene los datos que pido del Array. Es decir que si en el Array le mando datos como altura, nombre y edad tengo una clase que se llama Persona y persona esta de la siguiente manera.

```
class Persona{
public string Altura {get; set;}
//etc
}
```

y en tu método recojo el Array como:

```
public GetPersona(Persona p) {//.... }
```

En vez de un `string[]` guardo los datos en la clase y luego para acceder a ellos solo escribo p.Altura, p.Nombre, etc

Espero ayude